# Photoshop convert to video timeline creates layers for every frame

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So, this was working before.

I drag&drop a gif into photoshop and it would open as a video timeline (not per frames)

I don't know what i did but: now it opens a gif as a frame animation like this:
[image: first ss]

After i choose convert to video timeline, this happens
[image: second ss]

Again, this was working before. It's something I did today.. the only thing i can remember was that i got a gif opened up and i tried to convert it to frame animation and I succeded.. and then the troubles started...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking...

But.. much of this *depends upon the gif*.

Flat gif files customarily have 1 layer for each frame of the animation. When you convert that frame animation to a timeline animation, the timeline shows all the layers then adjusts the opacity or visibility of a particular layer at a particular time.

If you were to expand the view of the timeline layers you would most likely see opacity key frames for each layer to indicate when that layer is visible.

The only time a frame animation does *not* have a single layer for each frame is if you are working on a .psd file and not a .gif file. If you set up a frame animation and then save it as a .psd. The animation is *not* flattened. So, I would suspect the difference you are seeing is due to opening a gif file or a psd file.

There's nothing in your question which would indicate things are working abnormally.

Comment: i'm working with .gifs . I open a gif that I previously opened and worked fine (opened as a video timeline) and now it doesn't

Comment: In all my years, I have never once seen a .gif file open as a video timeline with Photoshop. They *always* open as frame animations.